# How to access lists in a dictionary and compare them?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

data.txt TXT file, NOT py

Mich->
Anne
Luke
Carl
Marl->
Fill
Luke
Anne->
Luke
Fill

python file:

```
    with open('data.txt') as f:
            dati = f.read()
            dati = dati.strip()
            dati = dati.splitlines()
            diz = {}
            for items in dati:
                if items[-2:] == '->':
                    key = items.replace('->', '')
                    if key in diz:
                        continue
                    else:
                        diz[key]=[] 
                else:
                    diz[key].append(items)
        
        print(diz)

OUTPUT:    d = {'Mich': ['Anne', 'Luke', 'Carl'], 'Marl': ['Fill', 'Luke'], 'Anne': ['Luke', 'Fill']}
```

I would like understand how can I access to lists and compare names here if elements of d are in an other file (data.txt).
for example, if I have to know which keys have the same names, what I have to do?
Thanks everbody.

I tried set, for do intersection, but I can't do this with this lists

for output I thought about (mich, marl and anne know luke)

I searched everywhere on internet how analise lists in dictionary, maybe its impossible?

Comment: Help us help you - share an example of the file and the result you're trying to get

Comment: Please provide more clarity on your requirement

Comment: The first list is accessed with `d['Mich']`.

Comment: Fill->                                                this is the file.txt for exemple
Mich
Luke
Mike->
Fill
Luke
Mich->
Ann
Ann->
Luke
Fill

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far (forming a [mcve]), example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: It's hard to read code in comments.  It's better to update the question and add the code there.

Comment: no, I have code, but I really don't know how access list in dict

Comment: where can I update code?

Comment: Use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65362333/edit) button below your question.

Comment: Click the edit button on the question.

Comment: Nowhere in your code do you reference `d`.. You're still not showing any relevant code

Comment: my god, sorry its my first day in this site, I will fix it

Comment: Please update with with example input and output

Answer (score 0):

One way to iterate the list would be like this:

```
d = {'Mich': ['Anne', 'Luke', 'Carl'], 
     'Marl': ['Fill', 'Luke'], 
     'Anne': ['Luke', 'Fill']}

names = []
for k, v in d.items():
    print(k,"has: ")
    for items in v:
        print(items)
        # here you can check if this data is in other file
        names.append(items)
    
    
print(names)
```

This will result in:

```
Mich has: 
Anne
Luke
Carl
Marl has: 
Fill
Luke
Anne has: 
Luke
Fill
['Anne', 'Luke', 'Carl', 'Fill', 'Luke', 'Luke', 'Fill']
```

You Should give more information about how the data is structured in the other file too, this all I can do with the information given

Comment: sorry, maybe I whrote something wrong... your result are the contenent of my file.txt... i would like to understand how say: 'Marl and Anne has Fill, Mich and Marl, Anne has Luke and only Mich has Anne and Carl' and to do this I have to access to every list in my dict. I would like know how, if its possible.

Comment: ok, in my code i do a Dict: [str] [list]... if I had Dict [str] [str] .... Do you think could I iterate and have my output?